Simplify grease pencil drawing in viewport for animating more easily?
I have a grease pencil object with a drawing/frame that I want to parent to an armature for animating it with bones.
My problem is that the drawing is a bit complex/has enough points to make my computer suffer when I move the bones and the mesh/grease pencil's points.
I tried adding a Simplify modifier after the armature modifier, but I didn't notice any improvement (maybe the opposite)
So I was wondering if Blender provides any solution for simplifying the drawing, at least in viewport simply for being able to move everything without lag.
(When animating a "normal mesh" in Blender, you can always duplicate it and remesh it to simplify its geometry, and move the armature without lag. Or even just hiding the mesh makes you able to move the armature normally. But with grease pencil, that doesn't happen. Not even hiding the grease pencil object, it seems like is being processed no matter it is visible or not)
Any idea?
